# CSS/PHP frameworks

Tags: css, frameworks

Are there any CSS frameworks out there along the lines:
Takes CSS "as it should be" as input, maybe with some additional functionality
Outputs cross-browser CSS, with all IE6 hacks in place, using JavaScript and ImageMagick when necessary.

Comment: Lots of CSS frameworks try to do this (like the ones mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854/css-frameworks-that-account-for-browser-irregularities) but they're necessarily limited in terms of the browser differences they can reasonably account for.

Comment: Here's the CSS you should serve to IE6 --- `body { display: none; }`

Comment: I am using this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCKi4zjq30Y

Comment: @John Flatness: the problem is that most CSS frameworks are written in CSS, and often CSS alone just isn't powerful enough to be cross browser, flexible and clean

Comment: The real problem is that there's no formal specification for "as it should be" in CSS, as in *"do what I mean"*. Therefore it's rather impossible to automatically make things display "as they should be" in all browser automatically. The only way to do that is to use a graphical tool to generate the "as it should be" layout and have it generate the CSS *and HTML* entirely. I.e. [iWeb](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/web/) and the like.

Comment: The "as it should be" part is indeed difficult. But "how it shouldn't be" is easy. A big part of that could be abstracted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're more comfortable with programming, and don't want to deal with CSS hackery, you could always try a preprocessor framework like [Compass](http://compass-style.org) which is built on [SASS](http://sass-lang.com). [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (built on [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org)) and [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) are also worth looking at.

Comment: Preprocessors are kinda like "Power CSS" - they add a level of abstraction that *can* allow you to create clean, DRY, semantic CSS. Compass in particular is quite good if you use just the bits you need. The img sprite generator is seriously awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [jquery ui?](http://jqueryui.com/)